# How do you get the branch spec that was used for a specific integrate in the depot history?

Tags: history, perforce, changelist, perforce-branch-spec

P4V's depot view shows the various branches and their paths, but not the branch names.
The branch spec (or branch mapping) contains the "name" of the branch.

Let's assume that user X has branched code from branch A to branch B using a branch mapping M some time in the past.

1. Is there a way to ask perforce which branch mapping was used for that specific changelist?
2. Is (1) still possible if the branch mapping has been deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible.

During the integration, the branch mapping is just a shortcut: after picking a source, you just pick a branch mapping, and the target is computed from `source + branch mapping`. Without the branch mapping, you would have to enter the complete path of the target.

You can check the information which is kept for an integration by looking inside the journal, or in a checkpoint.

In the depot view, I wouldn't say that you see branches, you see a tree; it's your usage, or naming conventions which make you see branches in this view  ;-)